LOGON Trigger on SQL Server
I need to create a logon trigger where I am able to capture both Windows and SQL Server authentication account users last login time. I am running into the issue of when I log in as a SQL Auth user with public server role permissions only and I get:
Logon failed for login 'xxx' due to trigger execution.
Changed database context to 'master'.
Changed language setting to us_english. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 17892)
I need to be able to allow users who only have public server-roles to login and track their time. I cannot grant them with any other permissions except for public.
This is my current trigger:
CREATE TRIGGER LogonTimeStamp
ON ALL SERVER FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @time DATETIME

SET @time = (SELECT login_time FROM (SELECT login_name, login_time, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY login_name ORDER BY login_time DESC) AS rnk
            FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions) ds WHERE rnk = 1 AND login_name = SYSTEM_USER)


  IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM db_admin.dbo.tblUser WHERE name = SYSTEM_USER)
    UPDATE db_admin.dbo.tblUser
    SET lastLoginDate = @time 
    WHERE name = SYSTEM_USER
 
END;

NOTE: This request comes from someone who has something similar in place on Oracle and not SQL Server.

Don't forget, LOGON triggers are run under the context of the LOGIN that is logging in. If that LOGIN doesn't have permission to do what the trigger want, and cause errors, the logon will fail.

In your case, that likely means that the LOGIN does not have a mapped USER in the database db_admin (and every (SQL) LOGIN will need one (AD Users could utilise AD Group permissions)) or their USER does not have permission to SELECT or UPDATE the table dbo.tblUser.

A little aside, but why do you need to look into dm_exec_sessions? Just use GETDATE() or GETUTCDATE() and do the update

Why do you need a logon trigger and a separate table anyway? Is there any reason you're not just using an XEvents trace?

@Charlieface i need a separate table because that's what my boss wants. Plus they want to be able to lock users out when they haven't logged on for a certain amount of time and then delete that account after a certain amount of time.

So why wouldn't an XEvent trace work? You can query it using the DMVs such as sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file and you can lock out users by just disabling their account. I see no reason to use a logon trigger or a separate table for this. You need to explain to boss how to use the tools properly, not just blindly copy over some concept from Oracle. Logon triggers are awful for a number of reasons and should be avoided if at all possible.

@Charlieface Trust me we've tried to explain that to him. Unfortunately, I have to figure out a way to give him what he wants in SQL Server. Sending emails out to users letting them know that their account is about to be locked or deleted due to inactivity is a bit much!

Have you tried executing a public procedure from your logon trigger that writes to this table? It can be set as EXECUTE AS OWNER perhaps, although, i'm not sure how well that stuff works from logon trigger. The downside is that anyone can call it, but it can perhaps be fixed as well. This all pretty ugly

@siggemannen Even if you can make it work reliably and securely today, it's still a time bomb waiting to lock everyone out of the instance, even regardless of permissions.

If you had a xevent trace which is periodically read by a job and saved stuff into a table, you can still lock out users according to your preferences by periodically check that table by another job. LOGON TRIGGER just gives you a bigger gun to shoot yourself in the foot with

@AaronBertrand i don't disagree, but it sounded like they were beyond resonable solutions

Since you've been committed to a bad idea, take a look at module signing. Which is to say that you can grant permissions only for the context of a given module (in this case, your trigger) and not have to grant them to the caller.

You can use the SQL Server log event to do so. Just change the default behaviour to trace all login, failed and successful :
USE [master]
GO
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'AuditLevel', REG_DWORD, 3
GO

Use the special procedure xp_readerrorlog to capture those event in a scheduled way by time interval :
EXEC xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Login succeeded for user', N'Connection made using', '20240901 00:00:00', '20240901 23:59:59.997';

This give you the login for 1 hour on september, 1 of 2024...
Of course you can store this result in a table, parse the data of the message and find the last logon... The name of the login is just after the first quote and the following quote

Would love to use the SQL Server log event but it was a request from my boss to put everything into a table to keep track of users so that we can flag their account to either be locked or deleted. This is a request from a person who uses Oracle and not SQL Server.

@TLew79 So why not just INSERT INTO dbo.YourBossTable EXEC xp_readerrorlog ...?

@AaronBertrand because that information doesn't help create a grace date for when the user's account must be locked due to inactivity. I appreciate the suggestion but unfortunately I'm dealing with a person who just doesn't get that everything that you do in Oracle cannot be done in SQL Server.

@TLew79 Why not? It stores the time it happened and the user information. So you can look at YourBossTable and find all the users whose last successful login was n days ago. If you want a periodic job that translates what it found in YourBossTable and puts it into a second YourBossTable that expresses it the way your boss wants to see it, that can work too. I'm not sure where the disconnect is here.

@AaronBertrand There's no disconnect. The readerrorlog just isn't what the team wants to use. I have no control over that. So I'm just going to let them figure this out. Thank you again for the suggestions.

@TLew79 Maybe the suggestion should be to move the data to Oracle if they don't want to manage SQL Server data the way you manage data in SQL Server. ¯\(ツ)/¯

@AaronBertrand I usually drive a car... But they ask me to drive a motorbike the way I drive a car... !

@AaronBertrand LOL..Oracle data is being moved over to SQL Server. I've worked in both environments and tried to explain that what you can do in Oracle doesn't translate well in SQL Server. The new solution is creating an SQL Job that will run every 5 minutes to send login data.
